# Comparing type mapped values in Slick queries

Tags: scala, slick

Consider the Favorites table object below, we want to write a query to find Favorites by their type (defined below). We have also defined a Typemapper, to map a FavoriteType to a String for the database

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
//Other imports have been omitted in this question

object Favorites extends Table[Favorite]("favorites") {

  // Convert the favoriteTypes to strings for the database
  implicit val favoriteMapping: TypeMapper[FavorietType] = MappedTypeMapper.base[FavorietType, String](
    favType => FavorietType.values.find(_ == favType).get.mapping,
    mapping => FavorietType.values.find(_.mapping == mapping).get
  )

  def favoriteType = column[FavoriteType]("type")
  //other columns here
```

This is the query I want to write (however it does not compile)

```
  def queryByFavoriteType(ftype : FavoriteType)(implicit s: Session) = {
    for(
      f <- Favorieten if  f.favoriteType === ftype
    ) yield f
  }
}
```

Here I have defined de different FavoriteType objects (this is outside the Favorieten Object)

```
sealed case class FavorietType(mapping: String) {
  override def toString = mapping.capitalize
}
object FavoriteType {
  object Exam extends FavoriteType("examen")
  object Topic extends FavoriteType("onderwerp")
  object Paper extends FavoriteType("profielwerkstuk")

  val values = Seq(Exam , Topic , Paper )
}
```

The problem I have here is that the query does not compile:
`value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[models.gebruiker.FavorietType]`

It appears that === can not be used to compare a User-defined type, is this true? Is there an alternative way to do this?

## Edit

Related issue: before I had my TypeMapper without explicit type, it was defined as `implicit val favoriteMapping = MappedTypeMapper.base[FavorietType, String]( ...`

When I would write a query that would compare a FavoriteType.Exam (for example) such as

```
  def queryByFavoriteExam()(implicit s: Session) = {
    for(f <- Favorieten if f.favorietType === FavorietType.Exam) yield f
  }
```

This would result in the error `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[models.gebruiker.FavorietType.Exam.type]`
The solution for this is the same as the one presented below

Comment: What scalaquery imports do you have? You should have org.scalaquery.ql.extended.<YourDBDriver>.Implicit._

Comment: Yes, i have imported scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

Comment: Notably I also get the error `value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column` when implicit Session was missing/absent from the query context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When in doubt with Slick, [go check out the unit tests](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/).  After reading their docs on mapping in a custom type and then looking at their unit tests, I got your query code to compile by changing it to:

```
def queryByFavoriteType(ftype : FavoriteType)(implicit s: Session) = {
  for(f <- Favorites if f.favoriteType === (ftype:FavoriteType)) yield f
}
```

Also, I had imported the `H2Driver` just to get things to compile (`import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._`).  I was assuming that you also had imported whatever driver it is that you need for your db.

**EDIT**

My full code example is as follows:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.session.Session

sealed case class FavoriteType(mapping: String) {
  override def toString = mapping.capitalize
}

case class Favorite(ft:FavoriteType, foo:String)
object FavoriteType {
  object Exam extends FavoriteType("examen")
  object Topic extends FavoriteType("onderwerp")
  object Paper extends FavoriteType("profielwerkstuk")

  val values = Seq(Exam , Topic , Paper )
}

object Favorites extends Table[Favorite]("favorites") {
  // Convert the favoriteTypes to strings for the database
  implicit val favoriteMapping = MappedTypeMapper.base[FavoriteType, String](
    {favType => FavoriteType.values.find(_ == favType).get.mapping},
    {mapping => FavoriteType.values.find(_.mapping == mapping).get}
  )

  def favoriteType = column[FavoriteType]("type")
  def foo = column[String]("foo")

  def * = favoriteType ~ foo <> (Favorite.apply _, Favorite.unapply _)

  def queryByFavoriteType(ftype : FavoriteType)(implicit s: Session) = {
    for(f <- Favorites if f.favoriteType === (ftype:FavoriteType)) yield f
  }   
}
```

Comment: I have imported scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._ , I tried the solution you suggested, however this did not fix the problem for me, I still get the error `value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[models.gebruiker.FavoriteType]`. This problem only occurs if I use === to compare a user-defined type, I can use === for Ints and other primitive values

Comment: @Fritsie, I posted my full code example, switching to your driver and things still compile.  I'm hoping that having all the code will work for you.

Comment: It turns out that `implicit val favoriteMapping: TypeMapper[FavorietType]` was the reason why your first code snippet did not work, thanks!