# Scala type resolution of inner class

Tags: scala, types, slick

The following code shows a module (in the form of a trait) containing two Slick table definitions, with the second having a fk reference to the first. Each table object defines an inner case class called Id, which is used as its primary key. This all compiles and works just fine.

```
trait SlickModule {
  val driver = slick.driver.BasicDriver

  import driver.Table

  case class A(id: TableA.Id, name: String)
  case class B(id: TableB.Id, aId: TableA.Id)

  import scala.slick.lifted.MappedTypeMapper
  implicit val aIdType = MappedTypeMapper.base[TableA.Id, Long](_.id, new TableA.Id(_))
  implicit val bIdType = MappedTypeMapper.base[TableB.Id, Long](_.id, new TableB.Id(_))

  object TableA extends Table[A]("table_a") {
    case class Id(id: Long)

    def id = column[TableA.Id]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)

    def * = id ~ name <> (A.apply _, A.unapply _)
  }

  object TableB extends Table[B]("table_b") {
    case class Id(id: Long)

    def id = column[Id]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def aId = column[TableA.Id]("fk_a", O.NotNull)
    def fkA = foreignKey("fk_a", aId, TableA)(_.id)

    def * = id  ~ aId <> (B.apply _, B.unapply _)
  }
}
```

However, if I change the column definition of id in TableA from

```
def id = column[TableA.Id]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
```

to this, by removing the explicit path to Id

```
def id = column[Id]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
type mismatch;
  found   : SlickModule.this.TableA.type => scala.slick.lifted.Column[x$5.Id] forSome { val x$5: SlickModule.this.TableA.type }
  required: SlickModule.this.TableA.type =>  scala.slick.lifted.Column[SlickModule.this.TableA.Id]
  Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
    def fkA = foreignKey("fk_a", aId, TableA)(_.id)
                                   ^
```

So the type parameter of the aId column is found along a path that now includes TableA.type, whilst the parameter is just expected to be TableA.Id. Can anyone explain why this difference occurs and how I might get around it without needing the explicit reference to the TableA object? I am trying to abstract out the definition of my primary key columns into a trait, and this problem is preventing me from doing that.

I am using the Scala 2.10.2 compiler.

Comment: What happens if you make your tables classes instead of singletons objects?

Comment: It just adds more code, as I still need objects extended from the classes for the table instances, but doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure why exactly your code gets a compilation error, but the following seems to achieve your goals:

```
trait TableModule {
  import scala.slick.lifted.{MappedTypeMapper, BaseTypeMapper}
  val driver = slick.driver.BasicDriver
  case class Id(id: Long)
  type Row
  abstract class Table(name: String) extends driver.Table[Row](name) {
    def id = column[Id]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    import driver.Implicit._
    def findById(id: Id) = (for (e <- this if (e.id === id)) yield e)
  }
  implicit def idTypeMapper : BaseTypeMapper[Id] = MappedTypeMapper.base[Id, Long](_.id, new Id(_))
}

trait Schema {
  object ModuleA extends TableModule {
    case class Row(id: Id, name: String)
    object table extends Table("table_a") {
      def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
      def * = id ~ name <> (Row.apply _, Row.unapply _)
    }
  }

  object ModuleB extends TableModule {
    case class Row(id: Id, aId: ModuleA.Id)
    object table extends Table("table_b") {
      def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
      def aId = column[ ModuleA.Id]("fk_a", O.NotNull)
      def fkA = foreignKey("fk_a", aId, ModuleA.table)(_.id)
      def * = id  ~ aId <> (Row.apply _, Row.unapply _)
    }
  }
}

object schema extends Schema {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val ddl = ModuleA.table.ddl ++ ModuleB.table.ddl
    println("Create:")
    ddl.createStatements.foreach(println)
    println("Delete:")
    ddl.dropStatements.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

In particular the `Id` classes associated with different tables are distinct so that

```
val aid = ModuleA.Id(1)
val bid : ModuleB.Id = aid
```

fails to compile with

```
[error]  found   : Schema.ModuleA.Id
[error]  required: Schema.ModuleB.Id
[error]     val bid : ModuleB.Id = aid
```

Comment: Very interesting. It's not quite what I need, as I am trying to use a cake pattern to be able to fold a number of table modules into a database object, but if I change Schema to be a trait rather than an object then I get close to what I want, and I reckon a few tweaks will give me a usable solution. Thanks very much for an innovative approach.

Comment: Bother. If I change ModuleA.table to look like this `object table extends Table("table_a") {
      def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
      def * = id ~ name <> (Row.apply _, Row.unapply _)

      import driver.Implicit._
      def findById(id: Id): Option[Row] = (for (e <- this if (e.id === id)) yield e)
    }` the I get an error `value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[Schema.ModuleA.Id`. Somehow the implicits that bring in the === are not getting found.

Comment: Sorry, don't think line breaks are allowed in comments, so that comment is a bit hard to read.

Comment: I do not see what what is causing the error, but maybe this question has the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147396/comparing-type-mapped-values-in-slick-queries

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a closer look at that question tomorrow and see if I can find a solution. The puzzler is that if I add the same `def findById...` to the TableB object in the code in my original question it compiles just fine.

Comment: The linked question throws exactly the same error as yours when doing === on user defined types. Their solution seems to be adding explicit types to make sure the right implicits are pulled in. This is similar to how I had to put an explicit type on `idTypeMapper` in `TableModule` to get all the implicit lookup to work correctly. The fact that the error only occurs for A but not B is just weird though.

Comment: The solution is to use `idTypeMapper : BaseTypeMapper` instead of `idTypeMapper : TypeMapper`, `findById` then works in both `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` but it probably makes more sense to lift it up to `TableModule` and have it automatically for all modules. I updated the answer code to reflect this.

Comment: In fact, leaving the type declaration of idTypeMapper off altogether, and letting the compiler infer it, works as well. That's great. This seems to be working as far as I've pushed it, so should be a good starting point for extending out to what I need. Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Great! Interesting that it works for you without any declaration. I get errors that way.